# Graphically monitor CPU - RAM etc over ROS

Tags: ros, quadcopter, uav, rosbag, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using an [ODROID-XU4](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825)  on a quadrotor. On the ODROID is running ROS. To the Odroid is also connected to a  camera [flea3 by PointGrey](https://www.ptgrey.com/flea3-32-mp-color-usb3-vision-sony-imx036-camera). I am launching the [pointgrey node](http://wiki.ros.org/pointgrey_camera_driver) to connect to the camera and it is working fine.

I am not sure but it seems that when I increase the frequency of acquisition of the camera (from 30 Hz and greater) the quadrotor becomes a bit unstable. It does not happen all the time but sometime. Because I don't know where this behavior is coming from I thought that it could come from the CPU/RAM which are *working too much*.

For this reason I was thinking if there is some tool which enables to store a rosbag file which then can be easily plotted to check the allocation of RAM and CPU when the frequency changes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250309/graphically-monitor-cpu---ram-etc-over-ros/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are not many runtime performance monitoring solutions for ROS. You can look at the following tools:

- [rqt_top](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_top) It's similar to `top` for ROS nodes running locally on your machine. It requires a graphical desktop environment to run since it only monitors the local machine it is running on.
- [drums](http://drums-project.github.io/) I wrote this tool two years ago. It should do what you are looking for both at host and process level. The documentation is far from perfect, but I may be able to assist you get it to run on your machine. You can log the data both to `rosbag` and to a time series database.
- [arni](http://wiki.ros.org/arni) This is similar to `drums` but with better documentation. The main difference is `drums` does not rely on ROS for gathering the statistics and also implements its own light-weight publish/subscribe middleware to collect and store the performance metrics. Unlike `drums`, `arni` comes with some fault recovery mechanisms built-in.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4